# Fixing PHP not showing on the website it self

Tags: php, ajax

Currently i have a simple way of doing this by using client side validation.

```
 <form id="mail" action="form.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Username</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      <label for="pwd">Password</label><input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
      <label for="email">Email</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and on the server side

```
<?php 
echo "Thanks for joining, " . $_POST["name"] . "!<br />";
echo "A confirmation email might have been sent to: " . $_POST["email"] . " if this were a real site.";?>
```

What i have tried so far in javascript

```
 $('#mail').on('submit', function(e) {           // When form is submitted
  e.preventDefault();                               // Prevent it being sent
  var details = $('#mail').serialize();         // Serialize form data
  $.post('form.php', details, function(data) {  // Use $.post() to send it
    $('#mail').html(data);                    // Where to display result
  });
});
```

When clicked submit the whole page turns into php's echo message. Is there a way to just show it on the website?

Comment: Maybe start reading about ajax (pure JS or using frameworks)... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ <--Start with jQuery if you want.

Comment: The symptom you're getting would happen if the jQuery code isn't running, so the form is submitting normally. Is it inside `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

This should handle that:

```
$('#mail').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $.get(
        "submit_page.php",
        {
            mail: document.getElementById('mail').value,
            other: document.getElementById('other').value //Some other value
        },
        function(data) {
            $('#mail').html(data);
        }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already using the jQuery library, you can use its ajax function to post data asynchronously and receive a JSON answer from your server without changing your current page:

```js
$('#mail').on('submit', function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax(
   {
  data:{"fieldName":fieldValue},
  type:"POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "destination.php",
  success: successFunction
 });
}

function successFunction(result)
{
 alert(result.message);
}
```

Your php may look something like this:

```html
<?php
    //Some php stuff

    $json['message'] = "A confirmation email might have been sent...";

    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Comment: `$.post` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax` that defaults a bunch of the arguments. Why should he use `$.ajax` instead?